# Burn - unwanted impersonation for MsiPackage

Tags: wix, burn

I am using WixStandardBootstrapperApplication to chain the install of .Net framework followed by my standard MSI package. My MSI package needs to identify the invoking user to write to the %USERPROFILE% location, however Burn requests privilege elevation from the start and runs my entire MSI under the elevated context. My MSI package worked correctly before being bundled in the bootstrapper - in that it only elevated after the InstallUISequence. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Burn installs all the per-machine packages in a chain from a single elevated process. Likewise, per-user packages are installed from a single unelevated process. There's no option to change that behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Bob. My MSI package contains an InstallUISequence which runs under the invoking user context and an InstallExecuteSequence which runs under elevated context when the package is executed standalone. In the initial phase I am able to access the correct user context when run unbundled to reference the correct %USERPROFILE% but the MSI also needs to elevate to install to %PROGRAMFILES(x86)% and write to HKLM etc. My client has a requirement to bundle installation of the .Net framework with the MSI. Surely this is a common scenario? What are my options?

Comment: Burn doesn't support that scenario. It's not common -- per-machine packages shouldn't have dependencies on per-user resources.